# Can the onStop event in a KML network link be used with Google Maps v3?

Tags: google-maps

I've been trying to get a simple example working where a kml layer within the google map will automatically update the contents on each zoom/pan. I've been testing using a simple server php file that returns a placemark in the middle of the specified bbox; our goal is to use this model to perform server side clustering. I've got the sample working in google earth using a php file linked through network kml.

Network KML file: 
    http://crv.vividsolutions.com/test/kml/layer2.kml

When I added the same network kml as a layer in google maps the php file on the server was only accessed the first time. The layer came up as expected and displayed the point in the middle of the screen, however after panning the map the data was not refreshed (the point was not moved to the center of the map). Based on the access logs, a bbox was passed down to the kml server with the first request, however there were not any subsequent requests. My test map can be found here: 
http://crv.vividsolutions.com/test/kml/index.php

I've located an issue which looks to be related (id=2697). [I could only include 2 links on this post otherwise would have linked it].

After trying a couple things, I did manage to get the desired behaviour however the solution involves dropping the existing JS layer object and adding a fresh on every pan. This seems a bit heavy handed. I was hoping someone might have an alternative solution to get the same behaviour without the overhead associated with creating a new Layer object on each pan/zoom.

Layer swap example (works but clunky): Same server as index.php ... just rename to index2.php [ran into the smap bot link limit].

Answer (score -1):

The KML reference says onStop is supported in google maps.

- [original link](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps) (no longer valid)
- [updated link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#supported-elements)

  partially   "onStop" is supported